# Facebook API: get video_id for ad creative but not returned for several ads

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Goal: get video media url using graph-api for all ads (no iframe)

Tried: `<some_ad_id>?fields=creative{video_id}` , and then using the advideos endpoint to get the source url. Outcome: sometimes I get the videoId, but for some ad creatives not. Consequece, I cannot obtain all media url's

**Questions

1. Why do some ad creatives not have a videoId?
2. How to indirectly get videoId if the field creative.video_id is not returned/empty? n*ote, using creative.asset_feed_spec.videos[0].video_id I can get a video ID but I dont understand what Im doing then***

*workaround to get the video url without knowing the videoId that for some ads seems to work:*

1. *ads that have a creative without a videoId seem in my case have an `effective_instagram_media_id`*
2. *for that `effective_instagram_media_id` I can get a video preview url using `<effective_instagram_media_id>?fields=media_url`*

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a answer on this question? I have the same problem

Comment: Did anyone have any luck with this? The `video_id` is not returned in ad creative API ever - and the video id in the Ad Video endpoint does not match the ones in AdCreative > asset_feed_spec > videos